# Gradle Android library cant find resources of main project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using gradle system to build an Android app.
I got some libraries that refer resources like @strings/app_name in their manifests. When trying to build gradle cant find that resources. Thats somehow understanable because I think the main resource file is generated at the end and dosent exist yet. But I can be sure that @strings/app_name will be there.
How to tell gradle that? Dont I basically just need to ignore that error?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the string in your resources?

Check at:  res -> values -> `strings.xml`

Even if you are not using it, It should be there!

Comment: The main project has it but the libary has no such file. By the way I forgot to mention that this is not a normal android project but a project exported from unity3d.

Comment: Allright In library you don't need it there. I don't use it myself in my library.
Try to remove from the manifest file of your library and try also `clean/rebuild` from `Build` tab

Comment: I think I shouldnt do that. In the libarys manifest are stuff like broadcast receiver and intent filters declared. Removing that manifest would break the project. I think if there is a way to process the manifests after the the merging of the resources it might work, but I just dont know enough about gradle.